# how to redirect any specific url to localhost in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, gunicorn, appdomain

I tried hard to redirect any specific url like `www.google.com` to my local host. But I am unable to do it.I am using nginx as web server and gunicorn to deploy my flask code. I tried in server block

```
rewrite ^http://www.google.com http://127.0.0.1:8000;

and rewrite ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8000;
```

and many other redirection but all in vain. But yeah I am able to do opposite of this i.e. `localhost` to `www.google.com`

thank you so much guys , I am really stuck here

Answer (score 1):

you're looking in the wrong spot:

for redirecting www.google.com to a localhost webserver you need to change your dns settings (most probably via your hosts file)

once you've done the dns change the most you'll need at the nginx-side is a `server`-block with a `server_name www.google.com;` so your server knows to accept requests for www.google.com

UPDATE: 
assuming I'm correct in that you're just wanting to redirect a particular request url on you need the following in your nginx config

```
server{
  server_name www.example.org;
  location /flask-app { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; }
}
```

that routes all http://www.example.org/flaskapp requests to your app. (obviously you change the domainnames, and add in whatever further config you need for the rest of your website)

Comment: I am new to setting in server. my main task is to run flask application when someone ping a IP or DNS which is of my site.so that he can get response in json format ?? so how can i resolve dns setting.can you please tell me ?

Comment: Not sure I'm getting what you want to do. If I understand you correctly you're just trying to run an app when somebody requests a specific url on your site? If so that ... has nothing at all to do with redirecting google to your loopbackadress. Updating my answer accordingly

Comment: Actually i want to run my flask app on Amazon web service EC2. now if someone ping my server he can get response from my server. I am using for that gunicorn + nginx. so can you suggest me some step for that. and my python code is                                                               from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello world!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()